# future plan(multisession()) error when setting workers

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-future

I am trying to use `furrr` to parallelize some code on a server with 144 cores available. When I run `plan(multisession(), workers = 10)`, I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot create 144 parallel PSOCK nodes. Each node needs one connection but there are only 124 connections left out of the maximum 128 available on this R installation`

I would expect, given other stackoverflow posts, to see this error if I really did request more than 128 cores. But I didn't, I only requested 10. If I request any amount I still get this error. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you provide some information how you run the code? Which OS do you use? Do you run the code in the command line or in RStudio? Thank you

Comment: It's `plan(multisession, workers = 10)`, not `plan(multisession(), workers = 10)`.  Details: I think the `multisession()` call will end up trying to set up a cluster with 144 workers, because I guess this machine has `parallelly::availableCores()` = 144 cores.